# Export csv file not working in safari using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to export the data to csv format. The following code working fine in firefox, but not working in safari as expected.

report.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Download CSV', reports_path(format: :csv), class: 'white' %>
```

report.csv.erb

```
<%- headers = [' Date ',   ' Type ',   'Amount ',    ' Amount '] -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<% if @reports.present? %>
<%- @reports.each do |report| -%>
<%= CSV.generate_line([report['Date'],
                       report['Type'],
                       report['Amount'],
                       report['Amount']]).html_safe -%>
<%- end -%>
<% end %>
```

reports_controller.rb

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv do
        log('info', current_user.email, 'File creating for Cash book..')
        headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="filename"'
        headers['Content-Type'] ||= 'text/csv'
      end
    end
```

can anyone helpme?

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you expect to happen? Do you expect the CSV file to download or just display in the browser?

Comment: do you have errors in your console?